# Find strictly increasing function that is a ring homomorphism

Tags: functions

I am looking for a strictly monotonically increasing function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$, for which

$$
f(a_1\cdot b_1 + ... + a_n\cdot b_n) = f(a_1)\cdot f(b_1) + ... + f(a_n)\cdot f(b_n)
$$

how can I find a (set of) function(s) that fullfil this?

A function that gets at least one step in the right direction would be

$$
f(x) = \text{ln}(\text{exp}(x) + 1)
$$

which is strictly monotonically increasing and which codomain is the positive real values, but then the sum of products cannot be solved:

$$
f(a_1\cdot b_1 + ... + a_n\cdot b_n) =
\text{ln}(\text{exp}(a_1\cdot b_1) + ... + \text{exp}(a_n\cdot b_n) + 1)
$$

**Bonus-Generalisation:** The function is also $f: x \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{>d}}$, where $d$ is any real value.

**Background:** I was hoping to build solve a linear system of $A\cdot b = c$, where $A$ is a matrix and $b,c$ are vectors, with the constraints placed on the elements of $b$ to be positive, by using $f$ on the elements of $A,b,c$. This of course would change results somewhat, but might give me a good initial starting point for more advanced optimisation methods.

Comment: The condition shows that $f$ must be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: Ok, I included that information into the question title - thanks. I am not sure though how this helps me to find the function - sorry, my math is not that great.

Comment: I don't understand the notation  $f:x \to \mathbb R_{+}$. what is the domain of the function?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The domain is $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. By taking $b_i$'s equal to $1$ we see that $f$ is an additive function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. So $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$ or $f(0)=0$. Also $0=f(x-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$ which implies $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Hence such a  function cannot take only positive values.

Comment: Is there maybe an approximation?

Comment: That is too vague. What kind of approximation are you looking for?

Comment: I mean that $f(a_1\cdot b_1 + ... + a_n\cdot b_n) \approx f(a_1)\cdot f(b_1) + ... + f(a_n)\cdot f(b_n)$ - or in other words $||f(a_1\cdot b_1 + ... + a_n\cdot b_n) - (f(a_1)\cdot f(b_1) + ... + f(a_n)\cdot f(b_n))|| < \epsilon(x)$ where $\epsilon(x)$ might be the error dependend on $x$ (could be a constant as well).

Comment: Ok, I think this might not be possible... when I think about your answer a bit more deeply - what I presented with $ln(exp(x)+1)$ is close to $x$ for $x>0$, but very much not close to $x$ for $x<0$.

Comment: @Make42 I have posted  a revised answer which I think is much easier to understand.

Comment: 1) How do you get from $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$ to $f(0)=0$? 2) Your reasoning would still allow point-symmetric functions though, right?